# Alert message if Autocomplete cannot find a match

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, alert, jquery-autocomplete

I have limited jquery knowledge where most of my coding abilities are self-thought. Please excuse me if my question is too simple for a seasoned pro.

That said, I am developing a drug reference webpage where a user can type in a drug name into the an input box named #drugs.

If a match is found, #submit1.click function sends the user to the match drug page. I was able to get the link work by using the .focus and .select code copied from other users (although, I have very little understanding how it is working.)

My question is is there anyway I can add an warning message to the user, if the user types in a drug name that is not in the source, the webpage will either

1. Alert the user that the drug doesn't exist.
2. Upon clicking the alert, put cursor back to the input #drugs field.

Thank you. All of my scripts are running on client side.  I have zero knowledge of server side scripting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var html = ".html";

$("#drugs").autocomplete({
    source: [
        {label: "Tylenol", value: "Acetaminophen"},
        {label: "Acetaminophen", value: "Acetaminophen"},
        {label: "Adenocard", value: "Adenosine"}
    ],
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#drugs" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#drugs" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#drugs" ).attr("data-value",ui.item.value);
    return false;
  }

});

$('#submit1').click(function(){
    var selection = $( "#drugs" ).attr("data-value");
    var url = "../Regimens/" + selection +html;
    window.location.href= url;
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll need to do is iterate through the list of autocomplete options on `submit1` click. Your click binding will become something like:

```
$('#submit1').click(function(){
    var itemFound = false;
    var $drugs = $('#drugs');
    var list = $drugs.data('uiAutocomplete').options.source;
    var selection = $drugs.val();

    for (var key in list) {
        if (list[key].label.toLowerCase() === selection.toLowerCase()) {
            //console.log("Item found");
            itemFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (itemFound) {
        var url = "../Regimens/" + selection +html;
        window.location.href= url;
    } else {
        alert(selection+" not found");
        $drugs.focus();
    }
    return false;
});
```

EDIT:
As for how it works, here is an explanation:

There is a special HTML element attribute (similar to ID, class, and style) that is formatted as `data-*="value"`. This attribute allows Javascript storage and retrieval of data. More info here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/. An example would be to store the last entered value in an input element. The HTML as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" data-last_entered_value="bar" />
```

This can be retrieved through plain Javascript with:

```
document.getElementById('foo').dataset['last_entered_value'];
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('#foo').data('last_entered_value');
```

Both of these will return `bar` as a value. You can also store/change a data attribute and it will be available script-wide for the life of the element in the DOM. You can change it using jQuery with:

```
$('#foo').data('last_entered_value', 'baz');
```

Now the power to the data attribute is it's ability to store any kind of Javascript variable (that I know of). So you can store objects by simply passing the object. These will retain their reference and can be updated dynamically. I won't get into that now but you can do some further reading on it as your knowledge increases.

THE POINT: When you make the `input#drugs` element an autocomplete, the autocomplete plugin adds a reference to itself in the data attr of said element. This way you can access the plugin after initialization.

What I'm doing is using that to my advantage and getting the `options` you initially passed to the autocomplete function. Within the passed `options`, you populated the `source` object with `label: value` (eg. {"Tylenol": "Acetaminophen"}).

Once I have an array of valid values to check through, I did a `for` loop to iterate through all those option pairs. In this particular case we could have just as well done the `for` loop this way:

```
for (var key = 0; key < list.length; key++) {
```

While iterating through the list, I do a string comparison to check to see if the user entered a valid option (I convert both sides to lower case so it will be able to correctly match an input even if the case doesn't mAtCh).

Comment: Thank you so much Adam.  Code worked.  Could you please explain to me what this code is doing?

   `var list = $drugs.data('uiAutocomplete').options.source;`

Comment: @TaeY.Kwak I'm glad it worked the way you wanted! And I can certainly explain it. Please see my edited answer for that.

Comment: Thank you so much Adam for the explanation.  I think i will definitely try to incorporate .data to my future programs. Thank you so much again.